# How to properly translate the key phrase of Erdoğan's 2016 letter to Putin, "kusura bakmasınlar," to Russian

Tags: перевод

**My question is this: What is the proper or most usual/standard way to translate the Turkish common phrase "kusura bakmasınlar" to Russian?**

Let me now explain why I got interested as well as the meaning and usage of that Turkish phrase and the research I have done.

Russian media and the Russian presidential website claim that Turkey's President Erdoğan apologized for shooting down a Russian military plane in his 2016 letter addressed to Putin ([link1](https://tass.ru/politika/3407975)),([link2](http://www.kremlin.ru/events/president/news/page/171)), but a central Turkish news agency, Anadolu, claims that the letter "did not include any words of 'apology'" ([link3](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/todays-headlines/erdogan-s-letter-to-putin-does-not-include-apology-/599158)).

[According](https://www.bbc.com/turkce/haberler/2016/06/160624_erdogan_rusya) to Erdoğan's spokesman İbrahim Kalın, the exact original expression in the letter is as follows:

> kusura bakmasınlar diyorum

"**Diyorum**" means "I say," and "**kusura bakmasınlar**" is a form of the common Turkish expression "**kusura bakma**." "**Kusura**" is the dative case of the noun "**kusur**," which is [defined](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kusur) in Wiktionary as "defect, fault, flaw," whilst "**bakma**" is the second-person singular negative imperative of the verb "**bakmak**," which is the Turkish verb for "to look," so the literal meaning of "**kusura bakma**" is "do not look at the fault." Here is how a native Turkish speaker explains the usage of "**kusura bakma**":

> For example, you are at your friend's house, you dropped the glass and it got broken, you would say: Kusura bakma, or Kusuruma bakma *lit. please neglect my fault*. Or perhaps, you met a friend of yours after a long time, he used to be married but not anymore, however you don't know that. You might say: "So, are you two still dreaming about having twins?". He would tell you that he got divorced, to which you could say: "Aah! Kusura bakma ya...".  ([Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C3%96z%C3%BCr-dilerim-vs-kusura-bakma-vs-afedersiniz.2048084/))

Another native Turkish speaker told me via Facebook that the purpose of saying "**kusura bakma**" is to inform that the fault was unintentional. "**Bakmasınlar**" is  the third-person plural negative imperative of the same verb "**bakmak**" ([link](https://turkishteatime.com/turkish-grammar-guide/imperative)) and literally means "they should not look," so "**kusura bakmasınlar**" literally means "the fault should not be looked at." This sounds different from the official Kremin translation ("извините") and seems to confirm the words of the Anadolu news agency that there was no apology.

What I am looking for is how "**kusura bakmasınlar**" is usually translated to Russian in, e.g., books or movies. The key question for me is whether the official Kremlin translation is different from the standard practice of translating that phrase to Russian.

I did my own research, but it has not been fruitful. In Reverso there are no Turkish-Russian translations. Reverso has a few Turkish-English translations of that phrase, but they are conflicting - "regrets" vs "apologies." On the Internet I found conflicting statements as to what Russian translation is correct, with the suggested variants being "[не взыщите](https://iz.ru/news/619714)," "[не обессудьте / не судите строго за ошибку](https://echo.msk.ru/blog/yashar/1791684-echo/)," and "[извините](https://iz.ru/news/619900)." I was unable to find any examples of translation of that phrase in books or movies.

Comment: краткость  - сестра таланта

Comment: @shabunc : Yes, I know, sorry.. I made a short version of the question at the very top. I don't know how to better explain the research I have done. It seems I am not talented...

Comment: I've closed this one because you're basically asking for translation without showing any prior research effort. You've spent too much time explaining what the Turkish phrase means but haven't make it clear why exactly you are still not satisfied.

Comment: @shabunc : I was afraid to add this, because it would make my question even larger, but now I will do that.

Comment: honestly, in this particular case your "here's the question and here's some additional context for those who is interested" is actually  a cheating - you can not expect the audience in general to know what the phrase means.

Comment: I gotta warn you that there's a very high probability it will be heavily edited in any case.

Comment: i have an answer, it took me less than a minute, but it's slang, in my opinion the question should be unblocked, it's fully valid and ON topic

Comment: let's give it a shot than, ok - that means that at least one user got the question.

Comment: Google translates _kusura bakmasınlar_ as _I'm sorry_ and its analogs into all the languages it has. Do you think the KGB edited it?

Comment: @shabunc : I just did the heavy editing myself by removing a lot of non-essential information and adding the research I have done. Please have a look whether the post is fine now. If it is not, please kindly edit it if you can.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка it's reopened

Comment: @Mitsuko I really appreciate that - honestly, now it's way, way clearer - thank you for you effort!

Comment: The case reminds me of a somewhat similar incident between China and the US quite a few years ago. In the end the Americans said "We are sorry!" and the Chinese claimed "Yes! They apologized!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what good Russian-Turkish dictionaries printed before 2015 write about **kusura bakma**.

Юсипова Р.Р., Турецко-русский словарь, Москва, 
Русский язык — Медиа, 2005. Около 80 000 слов и выражений. Страница 376:

[image: Юсипова Р.Р.]

The next one is by a famous Soviet turkologist [Nikolai Baskakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Baskakov_(linguist)):

Баскаков Н.А., Турецко-русский словарь, Москва, Русский язык, 1977. 48 000 слов. Страница 576:

[image: Баскаков Н.А.]

As you can see, both dictionaries translate the phrase as *простите, извините*, and also as *не взыщите* which I like the most, since the Turkish expression really does not contain Turkish verbs for *прощать* or *извинять*. *Не взыщите* actually means the same, but it is constructed more like the Turkish phrase, with a negation, and it can be roughly translated as "don't make me pay [for it]; don't prosecute [me], do not hold it against me".

[Взыскать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) on Wiktionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really an enlightening answer. So it is not uncommon to translate it as "**извините**" despite that "**не  взыщите**" is closer.

Answer (score 3):

My answer may sound flippant but based on what i've managed to gather from your explanation, *semantically* (not stylistically) suitable Russian equivalents may be slangy imperatives **забей** and **не заморачивайся**.

In more decent terms **не обращай внимания, не бери (дурное) в голову**.

The first 2 variants you listed are good literary alternatives.

My suggestions stem from my understanding of the phrase connotation in  the exchange between Erdogan and Putin. In the situation of a broken glass the slangy and colloquial expressions i mentioned **`will sound inconsiderate and rude`** just as they would in a diplomatic correspondence. And they aren't suitable semantically at all in the situation with a divorced friend. In Russian in such situation one would either say **a, извини, не знал** (women **ой, извини, не знала**) or without apology simply **а, не знал** (**ой, не знала**), because there's essentially nothing to apologize for. For having semblance of apology **сожалею** can be said.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now know more Russian phrases. But my question is about the **actual practice**. I want to compare Kremlin's translation with how the same phrase is **usually** translated in books and movies. The key question is whether the Kremlin altered the **standard** translation for political motives.

Comment: Do you really think the expressions you mentioned are really suitable in the situations with the glass and the divorced friend Mitsuko mentioned? As for me your expressions are used not by the party that did something wrong, but by those who'd like to soothe the one who did wrong.

Comment: By the way, if I were to translate "kusura bakmasınlar" to Russian, I would say smth like, "**не стоит придавать значение этому недосмотру**." Maybe even "**мы не нарочно это сделали**"? I am really curious how this phrase (or at least "**kusura bakma**") is ACTUALLY translated to Russian from any Turkish sources different from that letter by Erdogan.

Comment: @Mitsuko you'd have to ask Russians versed in Turkish

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка : Aren't there any Turkish books translated to Russian, with the original text available? Then I could search for **kusura bakma(sınlar)** there and compare with the Russian translation.

Comment: @Mitsuko i'm almost sure there are but i unfortunately am not familiar with any

Comment: @Yellow Sky i don't disagree, but this is how the explanation has gone over with me, if the guilty party say this, they will come off rude

Comment: I just read your update. Yes, **kusura bakma** is like **sorry** without formal apologies. After all, the friend who did not know about the divorce has nothing to apologize for, because he was not informed. The meaning is along the line, "there was no bad intent, so you should not draw any conclusions from the fault."

Comment: @Mitsuko **kusura bakmasınlar** may mean exactly the same thing but in a formal register due to avoidance of direct address through resorting to the 3d person imperative and thereby aiming to sound neutral

Comment: There are actually THREE forms: (1) **kusura bakma** (second-person singular imperative, i.e., **не смотри на ошибку**), (2) **kusura bakmayın** (second-person plural imperative, also used as a polite form to address a single person just like in Russian, i.e., **не смотрите на ошибку**), (3) **kusura bakmasınlar** (third-person plural imperative; there is no direct grammatical Russian analogy, but it is similar to **не надо смотреть на ошибку**).